# How to use the image between steps in bitbucket-pipelines

Tags: php, docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I would be grateful if someone could help me with setting up bitbucket-pipeline for my php env. What I'm trying to succeed is:

1. Build image in the first step
2. In the second step run some QA stuff like unit test, code sniffer etc.
3. Deploy to preprod envirement

Currently I'm stuck with re-using image from the first step. This is how my bitbucket-pipelines.yml looks like:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: Build docker image
          caches:
            - composer
          script:
            - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip
            - docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo_mysql json sockets
            - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
            - composer install
      - parallel:
          - step:
              caches:
                - composer
              name: Unit tests
              script:
                - vendor/bin/phpunit
          - step:
              caches:
                - composer
              name: Code sniffer
              script:
                - composer phpcs:all
      - step:
          name: Deploy to preprod
          script:
            - echo "Deployment"
```

What I get here is:
`bash: vendor/bin/phpunit: No such file or directory` - from "Unit tests" step
and `bash: composer: command not found` - from "Code sniffer" step

I already tried to set docker/composer to cache, save image in the first step and import it in the second, but still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to share stuff between different steps is to make use of [Artifacts](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-artifacts-in-steps/).

Basically, bitbucket spins up each step in a separate docker container. So a way to re-use material between steps is create an artifact.
The link should give you enough information.

For example:

```
- step: &build
    caches:
      - node
    name: Build
    script:
      - npm install
      - npm run build
    artifacts: # defining the artifacts to be passed to each future step.
      - dist/**

- step: &read-from-artifact
    name: Read from the artifact saved in the previous step
    script:
      - echo "Read artifact (dist folder) saved in previous step"
      - ls -la dist/
```